# Importing a Terrain type Google API static map into R without labels

Tags: r, api, google-maps, rgooglemaps

I'm looking to import a Google API static map into R using the GetMap function of the RGoogleMaps package. I then plan to plot data points onto the graph in R using PlotOnStaticMap. I would like to use the "terrain" maptype, but don't want the labels on it. I have found a previous stackoverflow question that addresses how to remove the labels on the map by using "style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off".

**Map with labels:** (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=29.4,-89.2&zoom=9&size=600x500&maptype=terrain&sensor=false)

**Map without labels:** (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=29.4,-89.2&zoom=9&size=600x500&maptype=terrain&sensor=false&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off)

This second code produces the exact map I would like. However, when I save it as a PNG file and then go to import it into R using the GetMaps function, it gives me the original map with all the labels still attached.

Does anyone know how I can get the map without labels imported correctly into R? It seems like it shouldn't be that hard, but I haven't been able to come up with a solution.

Thanks!

**Codes in R:**

```
smap<-read.table("D:/sediment/Rfiles/smap.txt", header=TRUE, sep= "");
library(RgoogleMaps)
library(rgdal)
MyMap <- GetMap(center=c(29.4, -89.2), zoom=9, 
                destfile = "D:/sediment/Rfiles/map.png", maptype="terrain")
map<-PlotOnStaticMap(MyMap, lat=smap$lat, lon=smap$lon, 
                     col=c('black'), add=F,cex=1.1,pch=19)
```

*smap is a data file of lat, lon coordinates to be plotted on the map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
MyMap <- GetMap(center=c(29.4, -89.2), zoom=9, 
                destfile = "D:/sediment/Rfiles/map.png", maptype="terrain",
                path = "&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off")
```